# Necessity and sufficiency of conditions

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

Is it possible that some condition is not necessary but yet sufficient?

As far as I know a sufficiency entails necessity. If something is not necessary then it can not be sufficient. Is that right?

Comment: [A condition can be either necessary or sufficient without being the other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency#Relationship_between_necessity_and_sufficiency) : see linked Wiki's entry  for examples.

Comment: No. Being necessary is not necessary for being sufficient, and being sufficient is not sufficient for being necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a condition can be sufficient but not necessary. For example, being in Paris is sufficient for being in France, but it is not necessary. More: running 20km every day is sufficient for being in good shape, but not necessary. Being 80 is sufficient for being old, but not necessary.

More generally, in any case where *X* is a strict subset of *Y*, being a member of *X* is sufficient, but not necessary, for being a member of *Y*.